# How to make grid layout grow vertically

Tags: html, css

I want to make a grid look which grow vertically like below,
 [image]

Is there any default layout which grew vertically, currently I am using `display:grid` `layout`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">item 9</div>
</div>
```

but it grew horizontal.

Comment: You can use `column-count`

Comment: like what ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

below is full CSS code

```
 .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
        grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }

    .grid-item {
      /* other css here */
    }
```

You can check the demo [here](https://codepen.io/SarathSantoshDamaraju/pen/JpJQRx)